# Jquery Mobile Back Button is not working

Tags: jquery-mobile, back

Can anybody help me and show me why in this code the back button is not working? I tried it on Chrome and also on Safari via Electric Mobile Simulator (http://www.electricplum.com/dlsim.html). I tried it also with the global setting with javascript ($.mobile.page.prototype.options.addBackBtn = true;).

The back button is correctly shown, but when I click/tap on the back button the page stays itself. In chrome I see that the Url of the subpage is shown (#sub-page) and after the tap on the back button the url changes back, but not the site itself.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width;initial-scale=1,user-scalable=0" />
    <title>Index.Mobile</title>
    <link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

<body>

<h2>Index.Mobile</h2>

<div data-role="page" id="home">

    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">

        <h1>Mobile Events</h1>

    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">
    <!---- BUTTON ---->
            <div>some content</div>
            <a href="#sub-page" data-role="button">Next Page</a>
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <h4></h4>
    </div><!-- /footer -->

</div><!-- /page -->

<div data-role="page" id="sub-page"" data-add-back-btn="true" data-back-btn-text="Back">
    <div data-role="header">          
        <h1>Page Header</h1>    
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">    
        <p>This is the main content</p>
    </div>

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Footer</h4>
    </div>    
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: careless scripting of attribs typo `rel="Stylesheet"` should have been `rel="stylesheet"`

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width;initial-scale=1,user-scalable=0" />
    <title>Index.Mobile</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<h2>Index.Mobile</h2>

<div data-role="page" id="home">

    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">

        <h1>Mobile Events</h1>

    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">
    <!---- BUTTON ---->
            <div>some content</div>
            <a href="#sub-page" data-role="button">Next Page</a>
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <h4></h4>
    </div><!-- /footer -->

</div><!-- /page -->

<div data-role="page" id="sub-page"" data-add-back-btn="true" data-back-btn-text="Back">
    <div data-role="header">          
        <h1>Page Header</h1>    
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">    
        <p>This is the main content</p>
    </div>

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Footer</h4>
    </div>    
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Try this...

Comment: I think it was messing up due to your custom css and the jQuery was not getting pulled from code you have written in the header.

Comment: Again crosschecked perfectly working in `IE9` & also `Firefox 7.01`